# What is the best (fast) way to develop play framework 2.0 module

Tags: module, playframework

When developing playframework 2.0 module, there are some steps you should follow (where I am wrong?):

1. create a module
2. create an application wich use this module

Then, everytime you want to change something in the module, you should check its work by application (which uses this module), so:

1. cd module-folder
2. play clean
3. play publish-local (it takes some time...)
4. cd play application; play run (or play dependencies?)

So, what is the best (*fast*) way to develop and test som module in playframework 2.0, could we crated some sample project inside the module itself in order *not to do publish evrytime and now wasting a time* waiting? What is the best structure to follow for this ?

--

Is it possible to define some module as a sub-project and work with it like with sub-project while developing it? then no need to do additional steps like clean, publish. But, i guess it is not equal to day that the module is a sub-project..?

Answer (score 1):

The steps you listed are the necessary ones, can't take a shortcut on them

You could try to speed things up via [triggered execution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Triggered-Execution.html), something like:

```
 ~ ;clean ;publish-local
```

so you do those steps automatically when you change a file.

Then have one terminal publishing the module and in another run the application. This could save you some seconds.

Comment: please put the comment as part of the question, will be more useful. A subproject may or may not work, never tried.